# problem with deploy asp net core app on ubuntu server

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, ubuntu

Good afternoon I am trying to upload my site to ubuntu server 16.06, apache2. My server without a domain is 183.56.54.34.
I have installed all the necessary tools to work with net core.
However, now I have a problem
I am creating a file /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/netcoresite.conf

And I put this in the config:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcoredemo-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcodedemo-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

After trying to restart apache2, the following writes to me:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

As far as I understand, this config is not compiled correctly. But how do I compose it so that my site works?

For deployment, I am guided by this example:
https://blog.todotnet.com/2017/07/publishing-and-running-your-asp-net-core-project-on-linux/

Please help me understand the problem, for a day I can not place my site on the server.

Comment: Have you actually tried to examine what the error is via
`systemctl status apache2.service`
`journalctl -xe`
commans?